# Share file from Mac to Raspberry Pi

Tags: file-sharing

I have MacBook and Raspberry Pi 3.
I installed Plex on Pi and all my movies are on Mac hence I want to make it visible for Pi.
I installed netatalk on Pi and could access files from Mac but Plex requires to provide just path to the file and not afp:// as I do. I can't do that
Then I installed samba on Pi and failed to configure it and make Mac folders visible.
Could someone please instruct me how could I access file on Mac from Pi by providing absolute path like /Users/xyz ?
Thanks

Comment: Netatalk is a freely-available Open Source AFP fileserver. AFAIK it is NOT an afp client.

Answer (score -2):

I suppose it depends on what you want to do with them but you could set up SSH.

Edit: oh, oops. I didn't know what Plex was. I'd say figuring out what ever is wrong with samba is your best bet.

Comment: Let me clarify. I need to somehow mount Mac folder on RPi. The goal is to access Mac from RPi as absolute path. Plex Media Server will work only with direct path to the file located on Mac hence I should provide something like /<mount_point_to_Mac/xyz Could someone help?

Comment: I think with an NFS server you can then mount the shared folder on the raspberry Pi

Comment: Well ... that is a good idea. How could I setup NFS server on Mac?